# Camel Route to XMPP Chatroom failing miserably

Tags: java, xmpp, apache-camel

I'm attempting to connect to an Xmpp chatroom on a local OpenFire server.  I have Pidgin running and can verify that OpenFire is working fine.  My camel route looks something like:

```
from("{{chat.timer}}")  
.setBody(constant("I will win!"))
.to("xmpp://superman@localhost:5222/password=secret&room=room1@conference.localhost")
```

However I receive errors in my ServiceMix log:

```
13:33:20,772 | ERROR | data.flow.start] | DefaultErrorHandler | 90 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.8.3 | Failed delivery for exchangeId....
. 
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getServiceNames(Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection;)Ljava/util/Collection;
    at org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppEndpoint.resolveRoom(XmppEndpoint.java:197)
```

And a few more "NoSuchMethodErrors" that are the same I believe.

I've got smack 3.2.0.1 installed in ServiceMix, I don't understand why these errors are popping up.  I can send Xmpp messages to users via Camel, this is the first time using a chatroom.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what version of Camel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, my runtime is using the servicemix smack bundle (version 3.2.0) whereas my compiled was using the jivesoftware smack (version 3.1.0).

I updated my compiled dependencies to the servicemix version and things are working.